# Oracle TABLE in FROM

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to understand what this block of code means. What does the TABLE mean?

```
FROM index_policy e,
**TABLE** (policies) p,
**TABLE** (p.plan_indexes) i
WHERE i.default_strategy IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY e.extract_id DESC,
e.cycle_date DESC,
contract_number,
acc_code;
```

Thanks

Comment: `policies` and `p.plan_indexes` are most likely collections being passed to the `table` operator.  `policies` may or may not be a local collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TABLE` is the syntax for a [table collection expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6).

> [image: Table collection expression syntax]

Which is defined in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) as:

> ## table_collection_expression
>
> The `table_collection_expression` lets you inform Oracle that the value of `collection_expression` should be treated as a table for purposes of query and DML operations. The `collection_expression` can be a subquery, a column, a function, or a collection constructor. Regardless of its form, it must return a collection value—that is, a value whose type is nested table or varray. This process of extracting the elements of a collection is called **collection unnesting.**